# blank page after recaptcha verification Authenticate with Firebase on iOS using a Phone Number Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

After recaptcha verification, page only returned blank. It did nothing to do next step.

**Screen Shot**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Did you make sure to set us your custom scheme URL https://coderwall.com/p/mtjaeq/ios-custom-url-scheme

Comment: I sure that I did all requirement.

Comment: The custom scheme redirect is not working for some reason in your app. That is the first thing that comes to mind, that you have not configured the custom scheme URL correctly.

Comment: Hi, did you solve the problem? My application was working normally, but out of nowhere, it started to return white page from recaptcha.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your app delegate's `application(_:open:options:)` method, call `Auth.auth().canHandle(url)`.

Comment: Certainly, it is the correct answer. You need to handle deep link redirection to catch that callback from reCaptcha.

Comment: I'm using react native and encounter the same issue, will this be helpful for me?

Comment: Should be marked as the correct answer and works for iOS 13.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution works! By the way, how do you know we should add this code? I cannot find where firebase doc specify this.

Comment: @WuYuanChun This is explain in the 'Appendix: Using phone sign-in without swizzling' section of the doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#appendix:-using-phone-sign-in-without-swizzling

Answer (score 5):

For the blank re-captcha page issue I was able to resolve it by doing these 3 things:

1st thing-

0. Inside the `GoogleSerivce-Info.plist` file make sure the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` is added to your project [via the URL types using this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin). Follow the first part of the second step there: *Add custom URL schemes to your Xcode project* (look at the screenshot).

[image]

2nd thing-

1. In the project navigator select the `blue project icon`
2. Select `Capabilities`
3. Open `Background Modes`
4. Select `Background fetch`

[image]

3rd thing-

5. Before verifying the phone number call `PhoneAuthProvider.provider(auth: Auth.auth())`

```
@IBAction func phoneButton(sender: UIButton) {

    // ***step 5***
    PhoneAuthProvider.provider(auth: Auth.auth())

    PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumberTextField.text!, uiDelegate: nil) {
        (verificationID, error) in
            
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
            
        guard let verificationId = verificationID else { return }

        // do something with verificationID
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On iOS, the appVerificationDisabledForTesting setting has to be set to TRUE before calling verifyPhoneNumber. This is processed without requiring any APNs token or sending silent push notifications in the background, making it easier to test in a simulator. This also disables the reCAPTCHA fallback flow.

[Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#integration-testing)

Answer (score 1):

I face this issue and fix it by adding this code into my AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication *) app
             openURL: (NSURL *) url
             options: (NSDictionary <UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *) 
               options {
                      if ([[FIRAuth auth] canHandleURL: url]) {
                           return YES;
                       } else {
                       // URL not auth related, developer should handle it.
                          return NO;
                       }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

If Anyone came a across such issu, Try this.

```
// Before verifyPhoneNumber Method

Auth.auth().settings?.isAppVerificationDisabledForTesting = true


       PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber( ....
```